# Zoom in and crop using ImageProcessor.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, imageprocessor

Using ImageProcessor.Web (http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/imageprocessingmodule/resize/) resize module, I'm able to get the image cropped to a defined size, like:

```
<img src="~/Content/img/fiji-01.jpg?width=500&height=500&mode=crop&center=0.1,0.1"/>
```

But how do I zoom in the picture twice the size and the crop?

Tried something like:

```
<img src="~/Content/img/fiji-01.jpg?mode=crop&center=0.9,0.9&heightratio=3&widthratio=3&height=500" />
```

It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set up Umbraco and use GetCroppedUrl method to see how it works. It happens that we use the crop module followed by resize module, like:

```
<img src="~/Content/img/fiji-01.jpg?crop=0.23159636062861869,0.061207609594706371,0.023986765922249794,0.19437551695616212&cropmode=percentage&width=500&height=500" />
```

or

```
<img src="~/Content/img/fiji-01.jpg?crop=50,50,200,200&width=500&height=500" />
```

Comment: Yeah, the methods are imperative, i.e they are performed in the order in which you ask for them. In your question you are are performing a resize that crops excess, not an actual crop-then-resize like you supply in the answer.